# React component can't find mapDispatchToProps Redux function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't get the mapDispatchToProps function to update. The console error  is `this.props.addPassFilePath is not a function` see the attached code and images. How to fix this error?

The Reactjs component is throwing the error in the changeValue function. It prints this.props.addPassFilePath does not exits.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addPassFilePath} from "../../../state/actions/index";


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    passFilePath: passFilePath => dispatch(addPassFilePath(passFilePath))
  };
};


/**
 *  Lists file names from get request
 */
class FileListingClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
  }


  /**
   *  Onclick value gets passed to this method
   *  it will then add it to the redux store 
   *  array called `passFilePath`
   */
  changeValue = (data) => (e) => {
    this.props.addPassFilePath({ data });
    //this.addPassFilePath({ data });
    //addPassFilePath({ data });

  }


  /**
   * Rendering html
   */
  render() {
    const data = this.props.listOfObjects;
    const dataArrayList = data.map(dataObj => {
      return (
        <li key={dataObj.id}>
          <span onClick={this.changeValue(dataObj.default_path)}>{dataObj.file_name}</span>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        {dataArrayList}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}

const FileListing = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FileListingClass);
export default FileListing;
```

I don't think the Redux Action is causing this issue. But just in case this is what I have set up.

```
import { 
    ADD_ARTICLE,  
    PASS_FILE_PATH 
  } from "../constants/action-types";

export const addArticle = article => (
    { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload: article }
);

export const addPassFilePath = passFilePath  => (
    { type: PASS_FILE_PATH, payload: passFilePath }
);
```

This image displays the error in the console.

[image: console error from browser]

Comment: you name the method `passFilePath` in your mapper, but reference it as `addPassFilePath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping the named function `passFilePath` in `mapDispatchToProps` object. You need to call it with this given name in your component `FileListingClass`. For example:

```
changeValue = (data) => (e) => {
   this.props.passFilePath({ data });
}
```

Comment: This is why always use the shorthand method :) `connect(null, {someAction})` No name confusion, no need to write some function definitions with dispatch.